# Filling non empty cells in column with sequential numbers VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have only started to learn VBA in order to make my work at office easier. Unfortunately, I cannot find a proper solution to the problem I want to solve.

I have a numbers in the A column starting from A4 cell.

I need to fill this column with consequent numbers.

The end is a first blank cell. The row amount can change.

Please refer this screenshot to see the input

[image]

This is a desirable output

[image]

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean replace the numbers in column A with consecutive numbers like 1, 2, 3, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean like this?

```
Sub Test1()
For Each cell In Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(1048576, 1))
    i = i + 1
    If cell <> vbNullString Then
        Cells(3 + i, 1) = i
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Alternatively,

```
Sub Test2()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row - 3 'Alternatively LastRow = Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown).Row - 3

For i = 1 To LastRow
    Range("A" & 3 + i) = i                'Alternatively Cells(3 + i, 1) = i
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @BangBoy You are welcome. You might want to have a look the edited version since I add an extra code.